# How to store client login credentials?

Tags: passwords, storage

My company has to constantly connect to remote server where there are numerous way to access, often via vpn and remote desktop connections, as well as SQL servers.

There are over 50 clients that this is the case for and everyone has different login credentials. Currently we store all this information on an excel spreadsheet that exists on a USB drive, that stays in a drawer. Periodically the list is updated and someone passes out a 8x11 sheet with all this info.

What is the best way to store this information securely, but make it easily accessible to everyone in the office? Is the best thing to do really just store it on a local server? Password protected?

Comment: No, that is not the best thing to do.  The best thing to do would be to use an actual privileged access management tool that allows you to control, track, and audit credential check-outs and check-ins.

Comment: The best way to store client login credentials is don't store client login credentials.  You've got a copy on a USB and who knows how many 8x11 sheets; you will lose control of these secrets, it is merely a matter of when. There are a wide variety of enterprise privilege management solutions that address this problem. If you can't afford a privilege management system, look for federated identity credentials.  There are solutions to this problem, you just have to look for them.

Comment: Why does everyone need access to those servers in the first place?

Comment: our software is installed there and we constantly have to go on the server to do updates or make other changes or diagnose issues

Comment: https://lastpass.com/enterprise_overview.php

Answer (score 2):

You might want to investigate Password Managers such as [Lastpass](https://lastpass.com/).  (This is just one example; a search for "Password Manager" will bring up many others.)  In addition to storing userid/password credentials for specific URLs, these systems have the ability to store files securely, so you could save all this information in a secure note, and then share internally to the people who require this information.